# Do std or boost have tag<T> or type_t<T> somewhere?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

Specificly im looking for something like this construct:

```
template<class T>
struct tag {
  using type = T;
};
```

This can be used to provide a template argument to a constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::in_place_type_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) might be preferable as a tag type for constructor. It is used by [`std::any`'s constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any) and [`std::variant`'s constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant).

Answer (score 5):

[c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) will have [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity)

Boost has [`boost::type_identity`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/type_identity.html)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [std::type_identity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity). The example implementation is exactly the snippet you posted.